# How do I begin to tackle this complex number problem?

Tags: complex-numbers

Update: here is how the problem should have been read.

Describe $z$ such that

$$
|z+5|=3
$$

Thoughts?

---

My attempt:

Let $z=x+iy$
$$|(x+5)+iy|=3$$
$$\sqrt{(x+5)^2 +y^2}=3$$
Solving for $y$ yields

$$y=\sqrt{-x^2-10x-16}$$

But does this describe $z$?

Comment: Missed class .... ask the instructor.  We do not know the notation he used in his lecture.

Comment: @GEdgar $z$ seems pretty frequently used online. However, I still can't figure out how to understand this.

Comment: ... which is why you should ask the instructor.  Or one of the other students in the class.

Comment: @GEdgar if I had that option right now, I would have done so, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: If we could understand your question, maybe we would have answered it, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Unfortunately, all I know is that we are learning about modulus and arg vs. Arg. I think the z is the only thing that applies here so that z= either 4i or -4i

Comment: @GEdgar edited the question

Answer (score 1):

A complex number consists of two (real number) components.
I hazard a guess that $z(1)$ stands for the first component of the complex number $z$; and $z(2)$ stands for the second component.
So $|z + 5| = 3$  means

$$|z(1) + 5 , z(2)| = 3   \Longrightarrow  (z(1) + 5)^2  + z(2)^2  = 9 $$

Comment: And the last is the formula for a circle !

Comment: Clarified the question!